# Change white-space color

Tags: spacemacs, faces, whitespace

I'm trying to set the whitespace color with something less visible, but for some reason is not applying it.

```
  (custom-set-faces
   '(whitespace-space ((t (:background "red")))))
```

this inside the `dotspacemacs/user-config` (on .spacemacs file)

is the correct way? there is a log to check errors? maybe something override it?

Comment: Your piece of code works for me, do you enable `whitespace-mode` using e.g. `M-x whitespace-mode` ?

Comment: Did you set this via `M-x customize-group` `whitespace`? I would recommend you to do it that way. After applying your customizations, you can find how it is done by Emacs at the end of your .spacemacs file, and if you really want, you could move those definitions to another location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well if works for anyone

```
(defun dotspacemacs/user-config ()
  (setq whitespace-display-mappings '(
                                      (space-mark   ?\     [?\u00B7]     [?.])
                                      (space-mark   ?\xA0  [?\u00A4]     [?_])
                                      (newline-mark ?\n    [?\u0000 ?\n])
                                      (tab-mark     ?\t    [?\u00BB ?\t] [?\\ ?\t])
                                      ))

  (custom-set-faces
   '(whitespace-space ((t (:foreground "black")))))
  (global-whitespace-mode t)
)
```

allow to show it as

[image]